# leveldb WriteBatch isolation

Tags: leveldb

If I get to write a lot of changes through a WriteBatch is there a guarantee that another thread won't read in the middle of writing to disk and end up with some new values and some old (which are about to be modified) ?

Documentation says WriteBatch is atomic (all or nothing) but what about isolation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Isolation is guaranteed.**

Take a look at the code below:

```
WriteBatch* updates = BuildBatchGroup(&last_writer);
WriteBatchInternal::SetSequence(updates, last_sequence + 1);
last_sequence += WriteBatchInternal::Count(updates);

// Add to log and apply to memtable.  We can release the lock
// during this phase since &w is currently responsible for logging
// and protects against concurrent loggers and concurrent writes
// into mem_.
{
  mutex_.Unlock();
  status = log_->AddRecord(WriteBatchInternal::Contents(updates));
  bool sync_error = false;
  if (status.ok() && options.sync) {
    status = logfile_->Sync();
    if (!status.ok()) {
      sync_error = true;
    }
  }
  if (status.ok()) {
    status = WriteBatchInternal::InsertInto(updates, mem_);
  }
  mutex_.Lock();
  if (sync_error) {
    // The state of the log file is indeterminate: the log record we
    // just added may or may not show up when the DB is re-opened.
    // So we force the DB into a mode where all future writes fail.
    RecordBackgroundError(status);
  }
}
if (updates == tmp_batch_) tmp_batch_->Clear();

versions_->SetLastSequence(last_sequence);
```

That's procedure of write batch, it apply for `[last_sequence + 1, last_sequence + Count(updates)]`, and will apply the sequence after all the update operation done. Which means that read operation can get sequence <= `last_sequence` before the batch finished, or get sequence >= `last_sequence + Count(updates)` after the batch both committed to wal and memtable.

Comment: Hm, got contradictory answer in another [forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/leveldb/qp67jTW5Yb8) : "... Get/Scan call picks up all data upto a specified sequence number ..." You could start a debate there so that the truth could be determined:)

Comment: hah, i looked into that, it seems that divergence we got here is that the updates have the same sequence or different sequences :) i will debate there later...

Comment: Consider a situation in which ```log_->AddRecord``` succeeds and ```WriteBatchInternal::InsertInto``` fails, What status will the DB be? The ```Write``` interface will return a status of fail, the memtable will have incomplete or no record of the writebatch, but the log file will have all the records and the sequence will be increased. I thought the log file shouldn't apply the new records but how is it done?

Comment: @jiafengfu according to the code, we ignore hardware ram error. 'WriteBatchInternal::InsertInto' fails only when the format of writebatch is error,  in 'DBImpl::RecoverLogFile', it fails the same way.